# How to return objects from filtering of nested arrays in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a filter based on books categories in my application that queries my mongodb. However, I am unable to figure out how to query such a nested array in the database. Given the following structure, how can I filter only objects whose categories contain e.g. ["Cookbooks, Food and Wine", Quick and Easy"]?

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Verified",
    "description": "In less time and for less money than it takes to order pizza, you can make it yourself!Three harried but heatlh-conscious college students compiled and tested this collection of more than 200 tasty, hearty, inexpensive recipes anyone can cook -- yes, anyone!Whether you're short on cash, fearful of fat, counting your calories, or just miss home cooking, The Healthy College Cookbook offers everything you need to make good food yourself.",
    "price": 7.69,
    "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51IEqPrF%2B9L._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-v3-big,TopRight,0,-55_SX278_SY278_PIkin4,BottomRight,1,22_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg",
    "related": {
        "also_viewed": [
            "B001OLRKLQ",
            "B004J35JIC",
            "B00505UP8M",
            "B004GTLKEQ",
            "B005KWMS8U",
            "B00BS03TYU",
            "B001MT5NXW",
            "B00A86JE3K",
            "B00D694Y9U",
            "B00DSVUVXY",
            "B008EN3W6Y",
            "B00BS03W5Q",
            "B008161J1O",
            "B0089LOJH2",
            "B00ENSBJYQ",
            "B00C7C040U",
            "B00DH410VY",
            "B00CMVFW4O",
            "B00C89GS1Q",
            "B0035FZJ9Y",
            "B004GTLFUK",
            "B00H24WT2E",
            "B00CVS44OW",
            "B00C5W32QK",
            "B00HY0KTPK",
            "B00BJ8IPJU",
            "B00JEOMV1E",
            "B0041KKLNQ",
            "B00CVS2JYY",
            "B00CTVOVD0",
            "B00ET594CC"
        ],
        "buy_after_viewing": [
            "B004J35JIC",
            "B0089LOJH2"
        ]
    },
    "categories": [
        [
            "Books",
            "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
            "Quick & Easy"
        ],
        [
            "Books",
            "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
            "Special Diet"
        ],
        [
            "Books",
            "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
            "Vegetarian & Vegan",
            "Non-Vegan Vegetarian"
        ],
        [
            "Kindle Store",
            "Kindle eBooks",
            "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
            "Quick & Easy"
        ],
        [
            "Kindle Store",
            "Kindle eBooks",
            "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
            "Special Diet",
            "Healthy"
        ],
        [
            "Kindle Store",
            "Kindle eBooks",
            "Cookbooks, Food & Wine",
            "Vegetables & Vegetarian"
        ]
    ]
}
```

[image: Book structure]

Comment: Please, provide a text example instead of a photo.

Comment: @J.F. i have added the text

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with the structure of your model seems not possible because unless I am wrong someone will correct me. But due to you have an array of array's you cannot really go through that as far as my knowledge is concerned. But the solution that I can think of is grab the entire document in memory and then run javascript **filter method** now that will definitely get the job done

Comment: Another thing that which makes me thing such a query might not work is you have this as an array the is no guarantee that what you have is at a particular index value **unless** you have the content filled in a particular order like the document you showed having what you want in index 1... But if my guess is correct then your solution here is saving content in memory and before sending back response back to client you will use JavaScript **filter** then now that will for sure work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need nested `$elemMatch` to get the result you want

The query is like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "categories": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$in": [
          "Books",
          "Quick & Easy",
          "Cookbooks, Food & Wine"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Basically is find into `categories` and query a nested `elemMatch` to raise the nested array.
Into the nested array, is only neccesary look for `$in`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DrjWz9w4iPr)

Note that this query will return the entire document that match any value into `$in` array.

Another [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SKHA2ErabtK) with more documents (and only `categories` field) to see clearer how the query works.